# What is the average lifespan of a Cocker Spaniel dog?

Tags: dogs, death, lifespan

I have a 9 or 10 year old Cocker Spaniel mix. There is definitely some poodle in him as well. How long is he expected to live?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Cocker Spaniels usually live to 14 years, but with exceptional care have been known to live up to 16 years.
- Poodles usually live to 15 years, (18 for a toy poodle).
- Cavoodles (Cavalier King Charles Spaniel crossed with Poodles) have a lifespan of 10-15 years; understandably Cavalier King Charles are a different breed than Cocker Spaniels.

Smaller dogs tend to live longer than big dogs. A cross-bred dog more *naturally* mixed as yours sounds, tends to fare better in terms of health and behavior due to a widened gene pool.  Unfortunately, a lot of *designer* hybrids can reveal health and behavior problems inherited from the two seeder breeds.

Without concrete statistical data for your dog, I can only estimate that your dog, being in good health at his age now, would have a good chance of living to 14 years, or longer with proper care.

---

References:

[All About Cockers](http://www.cherishedcockers.org/allaboutcockers.htm) (Cherished Cockers)

[Cocker Spaniel](http://www.pedigree.com.au/breeds/?b=57&p=c), [Toy Poodles](http://www.pedigree.com/All-Things-Dog/Article-Library/The-Toy-Poodle-s-5-Biggest-Health-Risks.aspx) (Pedigree.com)

[Poodles](http://www.burkesbackyard.com.au/factsheets/Dogs/Poodles/74), [Cavoodles](http://www.burkesbackyard.com.au/factsheets/Dogs/Cavoodle/2094) (Burke's Backyard)